# Как отменить событие scroll при достижении условия?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим есть событие scroll `$(window).scroll(function() {` следящее за прокруткой. И когда пользователь прокрутил к определённому блоку, нужно чтобы появился скрытый блок, и после этого нужно отменить это событие scroll, чтобы больше не срабатывало это событие. Как это сделать?
https://jsfiddle.net/m40bs5kz/2/

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop(),
            $title = $('h1'),
            offsetTop = $title.offset().top,
            height = $(window).height();
        if(scroll > ( offsetTop)){
            $('p').show();
            alert('stop scroll');
        }
    });
```

```css
.content{
  height: 1000px;
  background: yellow;
}
.content2{
  height: 2000px;
  background: green;
}
p{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <div class="content2">content2</div>
</div>
```

нашёл решение такое: `$(window).off('scroll');`
но что делать, если к этому событию scroll прикручены другие обработчики, нужно отменить только один обработчик, приведённый выше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать [event.namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/):

```
$(window).on('scroll.test', function() { ... });
$(window).off('scroll.test');
```

Answer (score 2):

Задаёте флаг, по которому отслеживаете событие. И меняете его при наступлении. Например, так:

```
var flag = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop(),
        $title = $('h1'),
        offsetTop = $title.offset().top,
        height = $(window).height();
    if(scroll > offsetTop && flag == true){
        flag = false;
        $('p').show();
        alert('stop scroll');
    }
});
```

То есть событие сработает один раз (когда flag == true), а после того, как flag станет false, больше срабатывать не будет.

Comment: событие то не отменится. и раз уж так делать то flag проверять сразу надо. `if (!flag) return;`

Comment: Вы проверку посмотрите внимательно. Событие наступает ТОЛЬКО когда flag == true. При наступлении события flag становится false, и проверка больше ни разу не проходит. А, значит, событие больше не наступит.

Comment: @humster_spb, событие не наступит и событие будет обрабатываться но ничего делать не будет (кроме пожирания ресурсов) - разные вещи.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, в данном случае разницы нет - человеку надо, чтобы один раз появился скрытый блок, и больше визуально ничего не происходило. Ресурсов на такую операцию пожирается минимум.

Comment: @humster_spb, не, я не спорю, в данной задаче может большего и не требуется, но зачем делать топорно, если можно сделать правильно?

Comment: благодарю всех за ответы, интересно было узнать тонкости обработки событий в данном диалоге

Comment: А я поспорил бы про ресурсы. 4 переменных, jquery, 2 сравнения, при том что scroll может прилетать по 60 штук за секунду. Событие то наступает, только сколько вы переменных и сравнений лишних делаете. В конкретно этом примере будет жеваться нормально, но если так говнокодить на большом проекте, то получим висящий букинг.ком.

Answer (score 1):

Выполняйте при скролле именованную функцию, тогда можно будет отключить запуск именно этой функции, а не всех обработчиков:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  console.log('Another scroll action');
});

$(window).on('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll() {
  const scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  
  console.log('Scroll action');
  
  if(scroll > 300) $(window).off('scroll', onScroll);
  
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```